# Any integer in 99, 999, 9999... sequence is not a perfect square

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I am learning number theory and trying to understand how does below statement is true .

```
Show that no integer in the following sequence can be a perfect square:
99, 999, 9999, 99999, ...
```

Comment: -1 Title is misleading.

Comment: Change your question's title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that all perfect squares satisfy $x^2 \equiv 0,1($mod $4)$, meaning the remainder of perfect squares when divided by $4$ is always $0$ or $1$. On the other hand, all these numbers you gave have remainder $3$ when divided by $4$, so they can't be perfect squares.